# locked by transaction: @console:Oracle (INTELLIJ CLIENT)

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea

I am working on IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4, Recently we connected database to the Client and it was working okay, until some recent times when we start getting error

```
[2015-09-28 10:12:55] locked by transaction: @console:Oracle - <<DBName>>@localhost
```

Now we can't perform any transaction as we keep getting the same error. We tried googling the error but could not find anything to solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I think there should be some row lock on the DB. if you have an Oracle DBA, check out for table/row lock. It can happen if the transaction exception occurred and rollback didn't happen properly etc.

Comment: how can i check that if i have some row locks, can you explain in detail the steps...

Comment: look for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending

also you can find locks using util **monitor session** by **SQL Developer**

Comment: [Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) — That's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this happen after a previous query I ran failed -- using PyCharm, not IntelliJ, but it is the same JetBrains system.  I did not have Auto-commit turned on.  Pycharm couldn't recover from the failed query for some reason, and it left an unresolved transaction active in the database.  I disconnected from the database (hit the red stop button in the database window), and then I was able to resume with new queries with no problem.  You might also try the rollback button at the top of the window with your SQL statements if reconnecting would cause you problems.

Answer (score 1):

Putting up answer for the same comment.

I think there should be some row lock on the DB. if you have an Oracle DBA, check out for table/row lock. It can happen if the transaction exception occurred and rollback didn't happen properly or a transaction is still open for a longer time.

You can execute the following query to check for the same if transaction is pending.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM v$transaction t, v$session s, v$mystat m
WHERE t.ses_addr = s.saddr
AND s.sid = m.sid;
```

Additional resources :

- [Oracle: How to find out if there is a transaction pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending)
- [How to find locked rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186848/how-to-find-locked-rows-in-oracle)

Consult with your DBA after your initial research. I'm not aware about releasing locks.

Comment: Following count statement returns 0 when executed. Also my database is working fine in Oracle SQL Developer. Its just the IntelliJ Database Module that is causing this error.

Comment: In my case, I couldn't run the suggested query from within PhpStorm because it triggered locked by transaction and when run from SQL*Plus it simply returned zero. Problem eventually went away when I restarted my PC.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If the oracle server is in your PC, then restart could have resolved :)

Comment: @KarthikR No, it's an external machine. I'd say it's entirely a client-side issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That raises my eyebrow ;) Thanks for sharing. I will look at valid reason.