# How to check the number of lock request(DML) in Oracle

Tags: oracle

As you know, Oracle needs to get a row level lock when DML happens on a table.
I wonder if we can check the number of lock request to a table for changing Oracle blocks.

The number of locks on A table.

Is there any dictionary view to find it in Oracle?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/locks.html

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:53140949357315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186848/how-to-find-locked-rows-in-oracle

Comment: Thanks. Motor.  Enough to think more.